# Get params from Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do what I want to do, so please tell me.

I have an *Item* model that can either be sold to someone (have a `sale_price` and a `buyer_id`) or be passed (not sold to anyone - `sale_price` of zero and no `buyer_id`).

Until now I just relied on the user entering the appropriate price/buyer combination, but I'd like to add a second submit button to the Item edit form that just says 'pass'. (`<input type="submit" name="pass" value="Pass" />`).

Upon submission by pressing that button, I'd like to override whatever `sale_price` and `buyer_id` has been selected by the user and set them myself.

I assume I should do a `:before_save` in item.rb, but I don't know how to detect the button from the model - or if it's even possible (or advised).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can differentiate the commit type in your controller:

```
def create
  item = Item.new(params[:item])

  if params[:commit] == "Pass"
    item.sale_price = nil
    item.buyer_id = nil
  end

  if item.save
    # ...usual rails stuff
  end
end
```

Of course, if you have the commit type in the controller, you can pass it into the model with a virtual attribute and use callbacks if you like:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord:Model
  attr_accessor :pass

  before_save :reset_sale_price

  private

  def reset_sale_price
    if pass
      self.sale_price = nil
      self.buyer_id = nil
    end
  end
end

class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    item = Item.new(params[:item])
    item.pass = (params[:commit] == "Pass")

    if item.save
      #... standard rails stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Why do you need to put stuff in the controller? Your model is enough.

Comment: I think he was giving me the option of doing it either way. I went with the second block of code and it worked nicely.